# Typescript generics and returning functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I have a function that accepts another function as an argument, and returns a function having the same input type signature, but `void` instead of whatever output type the inner function had. The actual code does some other things, but here's the dumbed down version of it. I just can't seem to get the types right. Here's what I have so far (I'm aware it's wrong):

```
export function foo<Type>(func : (_ : Type) => any) {
  return function bar(...args : Type) : void {
    func.apply(null, args)
  }
}
```

The first line doesn't really capture what I want it to - the entire argument list of `func` should be `Type`, not just the first argument. I can't seem to be able to do so, though. (Note that `Type[]` doesn't capture the intended use, since not all arguments need to be the same type.) Is this even possible given the generics that Typescript offers?

Comment: You just need tk extend any and use a rest parameter in your signature https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIhAHgBUBPMYOUGYFAEwGc4BDFEgbQF0A+ACmXTgAuODwB04gPpC4pcgEo4AXi7NWCgN4AoOHCjAYSKLn4ZsuAEZMoY8VYDmjYbOALhANwiZacLTp0nRJjAwABsSHhQkEJCAGmYoBzltOABfTRSgA

Comment: Just found `Parameters<typeof func>` as type for `...args`, though the extension also seems like a legit approach.

Comment: `Parameters<typeof func>` can work. But unless you need the type of the function itself, using a type parameter for the arguments and one for the return type generally works better (conditional types such as `Parameeters` generally don't rezolve in teh implementation and may require type assertions)